# Java: How to modify value of current enum inside of its type definition?

Tags: java

I defined an enum type that implements an interface as follows:

```
public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface
{
    val1, val2, val3;
    private MyEnum() {}
    private MyEnum(Parcel in)
    {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        MyEnum val = MyEnum.values()[in.readInt()];
        // ??? How to I assign val to my current enum?
    }

}
```

How do I access the value of the current enum object so I can make the assignment inside of `readFromParcel()` ? (Please see comment in code)

Comment: If you write more about what you're trying to do, I'm sure we can answer your question adequately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside an instance method, you can refer to the "current `enum` object" as simply `this`. It works this way because `enum` constants are actual objects, i.e. instances of a `class` -- a very special type of `class`, but a `class` nonetheless. (Note that I mentioned that these are `enum` constants: it is the convention in Java to use all uppercase letters when naming constants.)

Your usage of `values()` is also very peculiar (not to mention that it'll perform horribly since a new array must be constructed at each call). Perhaps you'd want to take a look at [`EnumMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html), which is a special kind of [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) optimized for `enum` constants as keys.

If you're trying to mutate fields contained in these `enum` constants, then you should seriously consider a redesign. You should generally minimize mutability anyway, but having these `static` singletons be mutable does not sound like a good design. Instead of having these mutable fields intrinsic within the `enum` constants themselves, a `Map` from the constants to these mutable values would be a much better design.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition*

  - Item 15: Minimize mutability
  - Item 31: Use instance fields instead of ordinals
  - Item 32: Use [`EnumSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) instead of bit fields
  - Item 33: Use [`EnumMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) instead of ordinal indexing

#### Various questions on Java `enum`

- [Configurable Values in Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902113/configurable-values-in-enum)
- [How to efficiently use Enum objects as keys in the Map data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029850/how-to-efficiently-use-enum-objects-as-keys-in-the-map-data-structure)
- [Is there a a C-like way to get item number from enum in java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765687/is-there-a-a-c-like-way-to-get-item-number-from-enum-in-java) (yes, but why would you???)
- [Get enum by its inner field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780129/get-enum-by-its-inner-field)

Answer (score 1):

Enums are immutable, so you cannot. Your best be is to make `readFromParcel` static and have it return an enum. So, something like this:

```
    public static MyEnum readFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        MyEnum val = MyEnum.values()[in.readInt()];
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: They aren't necessarily immutable; they just should be.

Comment: Enums are immutable, the ordinal and name fields are final. You can't have an instance of an enum read a value and become a different instance. It just won't work. Now, if you add additional data, that can be mutable. But mutable data for an enum means you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not a good idea to make enums mutable. However, the `this` for an `enum` is just `this`.

```
MyEnum val = this;
```

The actual fields `val1`, `val2` and `val3` (should be `VAL1`, `VAL2` and `VAL3`) are implicitly `public static final`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **this**.

```
if this.equals(val) {
     ...
}
```